# Set metadata for several tests across multiple files in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am writing many tests with vcr as metadata with the following syntax:

```
  vcr_options = {allow_playback_repeats: true, :record => :new_episodes, :re_record_interval => 7.days}

  describe 'a User with no enabled services' do
    it 'any system page should show a request to add needed service providers', {vcr: vcr_options, :js => true} do
      ...
    end
  end
```

Because most of my tests make web calls, I want to be able to set every test in a file or a folder of files to use vcr automatically, with that option set.

Instead of:

```
vcr_options = {allow_playback_repeats: true, :record => :new_episodes, :re_record_interval => 7.days}

describe 'blah blah' do
    it 'blah blah', vcr: vcr_options do
      ...
    end

    it 'blah blah blah', vcr: vcr_options do
      ...
    end
  end

describe 'etc etc' do
    it 'etc etc', {vcr: vcr_options, js: true} do
      ...
    end

    it 'etc etc etc, vcr: vcr_options do
      ...
    end
  end
```

I want to simply write the tests normally and have each it block assume the test should be run with vcr and vcr options (with a metadata set for the few tests that don't).  How can I make this happen?

Comment: Have a look here: https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-5-0/docs/test-frameworks/usage-with-rspec-macro. If you use a VCR macro and a RSpec global `before` block I'm sure you could make it work.

Comment: VCR::RSpec::Macros is deprecated. Running it asks people to use RSpec metadata options instead `:vcr => vcr_options`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the VCR options at the example group level, and it will apply to all examples within the example group (or any nested groups):

```
describe SomeClass, vcr: vcr_options do
  it 'uses VCR without explicitly using VCR metadata at this level' do
  end
end
```